# Trying to get propperty of non-object Mysqli result

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "job_database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['Get']))
{
    $jtitle = $_POST['jobtitle'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $category = $_POST['categories'];
    //Query specified database for value
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM addjob where jtitle ='$jtitle' &and; location ='$location' &and; category ='$category' " ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "jtitle: " . $row["jtitle"]. "location:" . $row["location"]. "category" . $row["category"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: There is `&and;` instead of `and` in your query ...

Comment: `&and;` < do you know what that does? I'll tell you; it "ends" the statement.

Comment: the ampersand, well that is just odd as to why you have that.

Comment: voting this one as a typo.

Comment: real nice sql injection there, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sql query as follows,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addjob WHERE jtitle =".$jtitle." AND location =".$location." AND category =".$category." ;
```

since `&and;` is wrong, what it does is, it ends the SQL query because there is `;` in the end. So change `&and;` into `and` and check.

And read more about [form validation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) and [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) from these links.

Good luck! =)

Comment: i will .but still nothing change 

Comment: still echo the samething and 0 result

Comment: if ($result->num_rows > 0) the error is in this line says